# It was done yesterday. It had been done yesterday

Tags: sentence-construction

It was done yesterday. 
It had been done yesterday. 
Which one is correct?  Clarify the difference.

Comment: both mean the same thing, just the latter one talks about 'distant future' i.e. more past in past!

Comment: Any other solid and superb logic?

Comment: it's not *logic*, it's *grammar*, and hence no other option! :)

Comment: Thanks for that. I want to know about others views concerning these sentences.  Anyway thanks for adding your pleasant comments.

Comment: "Correct" in what sense? We're going to need more context.

Comment: I asked someone about these sentences.  He replied,  Sentence obne is correct. 2 as a single sentence isn't correct. He said, as past perfect is the " pre-past in relation to a past.Here we have only one event in the past time.  Not with one event before other.

Comment: See http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33342/using-of-past-perfect

Comment: I don't think this is a proofreading request. It was clear to me that the the OP was asking a complicated grammar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most contexts the first one is correct. Use the simple past to indicate an action that was completed in the past.

> It was done yesterday.

Use the present perfect passive to indicate an action that was completed at an unspecified time in the past.

> It has been done yesterday.

In this context the past perfect passive doesn't work at all, unless you add some conditions to the sentence, like:

> If it had been done yesterday, I would have it by now.