# Using past perfect

Tags: past-perfect

Why do we use the simple past with "was driving" and not the past perfect?

**He had probably crashed because he had gone to sleep while he was driving**

I have taken this phrase from the topic below:

< [https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33342/using-of-past-perfect?r=SearchResults>](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33342/using-of-past-perfect?r=SearchResults%3E)

Comment: _He was driving_ is the continuous tense. He was in the act of driving at the moment that he fell asleep. To use _while he had been driving_ would make the sentence unnecessarily cumbersome without making the meaning any clearer.

Comment: More pertinently, why did you cast the primary verb in the Past Perfect? Unless prior context *required* it, you should almost certainly have started with plain ***He probably crashed because...***

Comment: As I understand, the primary verb was casted in the Past Perfect because of the context of the previous sentence. I was just wondering why do not we put all verbs in this sentence into Past Perfect, as all these actions were conducted prior to the reference time. Could you tell me, is it always like this with Continious tense - we do not put it into Past Perfect, even if it was conducted before the reference time?